# Gap inconsistencies using CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this html document in which I'm using a CSS grid:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-IT">

    <head>
    
        <title>Site</title>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <style>

            .grid1 {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1rem);
                grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1rem);
                row-gap: 1px;
                column-gap: 1px;
            }

            .cell1 {
                fill:rgb(130, 190, 234);
                stroke-width:0;
                stroke:rgb(0,0,0);
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body id="mainBody">

        <div class="grid1">
             <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect class="cell1"/>
             </svg>
             <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect class="cell1"/>
             </svg>
             <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect class="cell1"/>
             </svg>
             <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect class="cell1"/>
             </svg>
             <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect class="cell1"/>
             </svg>
             <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect class="cell1"/>
             </svg>
             <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect class="cell1"/>
             </svg>
             <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect class="cell1"/>
             </svg>
             <svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect class="cell1"/>
             </svg>
        </div>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

but, even though I set the row gap and column gap to be 1px, I still get this:

[image]

As you can see, the first column gap and row gap are instead 2px wide. If I increase the number of row and column, the pattern repeats. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is this only with a 1px gap? Does it double with any other size?

Comment: @Paulie_D if I set a 2px gap, it's consinstent, but it actually set a 3px gap.

Comment: Sounds like a pixel rounding issue by the browser. Not sure there is anything you can do here.

Comment: @Frax I think it depends on the browser. I looked in Chrome and Firefox of the latest versions, everything is fine there

Comment: @Paulie_D ...then what's the point in the ability to set a fixed pixel gap? There must be something I can do...

Comment: How the browser interprets the gap is independent of the css spec. Just sounds like one of those things.

Comment: Perhaps use a fractional rem value instead of a pixel and see what happens.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I even tried Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer. For me it's working on both too, next to firefox and chrome.

Comment: Most likely, you have scaling enabled - either in the browser or in the system.

Comment: Remember you are talking in CSS pixels where one CSS pixel may map onto several screen pixels. It may depend on where your grid items fall as to exactly what size gap you get - it can be a sort of rounding error.

Comment: @Geilmaker I am using Google Chrome...

Comment: I can replicate this problem by zooming in 150% (Chrome 114, FF 114, Edge 114).

Comment: Is your browser zoomed in?   Press `Ctrl` + `0` to reset your zoom level

Comment: @ChrisBarr no, it's not

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

Replace:

```
.grid1 {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1rem);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1rem);
        row-gap: 1px;
        column-gap: 1px;
    }
```

Replace with:

```
.grid1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1rem);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1rem);
    gap: 1px;

}
```

gap:1px is what you need.

But, you also need to set a width and height to .grid1, for example:

```
.grid1 {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1rem);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1rem);
        gap: 1px;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    
    }
```

If you are unsure about the width and height, just set them to `width:auto; height:auto;` and let the content inside the grid decide the width and height.

Comment: [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) is a shorthand for `row-gap` and `column-gap`, so your suggestion doesn't make a difference in rendering. Additionally, the width and height are set to `1rem` in the template declarations.

Comment: 1rem is only for 1 grid not the set of grids so you are wrong Tim

Comment: Actually, the [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) function sets the entire track, not just one. Here's a [Grid Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids)

Comment: I think the guy asking (Frax) should give it a try to this answer because 1fr as Marcus says, means nothing if there is not a width and height in some container and that is easy to test Tim R, create a Grid 1 row 2 column and you will get no 100% height neither 100vh and not even 1fr but just a small line about 5px height.  And by the way, 1fr can be 1px if the width of the grid is set to 2px, so you can never trust that 1fr is just 1fr without a defined size  first.